# Reading objects from shiny output object not allowed?

Tags: r, shiny, scatter-plot, shiny-server

I'm trying to write a little app that will allow the user to make a scatterplot, select a subset of points on the plot, then output a table in .csv format with just those selected points. I figured out how to get the page up and running and how to select points using brushedPoints. The table with selected points appears but when I press the Download button, the error "Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed." appears. Am I unable to download the table that I can visually see on the screen as a .csv? If so, is there a workaround?

I've recreated the problem using the iris dataset below. Any help figuring out why I cannot download the table of displayed rows would be greatly appreciated.

```
data(iris)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", brush = "plot_brush"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info"),mainPanel(downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=factor(Species))) + 
    theme_bw()
  })

  output$info <- renderPrint({
brushedPoints(iris, input$plot_brush, xvar = "Sepal.Width", yvar = "Sepal.Length")
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { 
        paste('SelectedRows', '.csv', sep='') },
        content = function(file) {
        write.csv(output$info, file)
      }
  )

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The issue is that the output object is generating all of the web display stuff as well. Instead, you need to pull the data separately for the download. You could do it with a second call to `brushedPoints` in the download code. Better, however, is to use a `reactive()` function to do it just once, then call that everywhere that you need it. Here is how I would modify your code to make that work:

```
data(iris)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", brush = "plot_brush"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info"),mainPanel(downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length)) + geom_point(aes(color=factor(Species))) + theme_bw()
  })


  selectedData <- reactive({
    brushedPoints(iris, input$plot_brush)
  })

  output$info <- renderPrint({
    selectedData()
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste('SelectedRows', '.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(selectedData(), file)
    }
  )

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

(Note, with `ggplot2`, you do not need to explicitly set `xvar` and `yvar` in `brushedPoints`. So, I removed it here to increase the flexibility of the code.)

I am not aware of any "lasso" style free drawing ability in `shiny` (though, give it a week -- they are constantly adding fun tools). However, you can mimic the behavior by allowing user to select multiple regions and/or to click on individual points. The server logic gets a lot messier, as you need to store the results in a `reactiveValues` object to be able to use it repeatedly. I have done something similar to allow me to select points on one plot and highlight/remove them on other plots. That is more complicated than what you need here, but the below should work. You may want to add other buttons/logic (e.g., to "reset" the selections), but I believe that this should work. I did add a display of the selection to the plot to allow you to keep track of what has been selected.

```
data(iris)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", brush = "plot_brush", click = "plot_click")
  , actionButton("toggle", "Toggle Seletion")
  , verbatimTextOutput("info")
  , mainPanel(downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(withSelected()
           , aes(x=Sepal.Width
                 , y=Sepal.Length
                 , color=factor(Species)
                 , shape = Selected)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_shape_manual(
        values = c("FALSE" = 19
                   , "TRUE" = 4)
      , labels = c("No", "Yes")
      , name = "Is Selected?"
      ) +
      theme_bw()
  })

  # Make a reactive value -- you can set these within other functions
  vals <- reactiveValues(
    isClicked = rep(FALSE, nrow(iris))
  )


  # Add a column to the data to ease plotting
  # This is really only necessary if you want to show the selected points on the plot
  withSelected <- reactive({
    data.frame(iris
               , Selected = vals$isClicked)
  })



  # Watch for clicks
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {

    res <- nearPoints(withSelected()
                      , input$plot_click
                      , allRows = TRUE)

    vals$isClicked <-
      xor(vals$isClicked
          , res$selected_)
  })


  # Watch for toggle button clicks
  observeEvent(input$toggle, {
    res <- brushedPoints(withSelected()
                         , input$plot_brush
                         , allRows = TRUE)

    vals$isClicked <-
      xor(vals$isClicked
          , res$selected_)
  })

  # pull the data selection here
  selectedData <- reactive({
    iris[vals$isClicked, ]
  })

  output$info <- renderPrint({
    selectedData()
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
      paste('SelectedRows', '.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(selectedData(), file)
    }
  )

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Mark, this worked perfectly! The reactive function is especially helpful, thanks for bringing it to my attention. Thanks so much.

Comment: Mark, it occurred to me that the brushedPoints option only allows the user to select points within a rectangle. Is there a "lasso" option possible? I searched around but couldn't find anything but the "lasso" option in Plot.ly which would require a huge rewrite of the above script.

Comment: Not directly, that I am aware of. However, I did just add an edit that shows how to do multiple selections -- that may give you the same behavior in the end.

Comment: Mark, your solution works extremely well for me. I can't thank you enough. The multiple selections does indeed give the same behavior as I was hoping to achieve with lasso. I especially like how you configured it so that the markers change shape depending on whether they are selected or not. I'm hoping that with more practice I can start making more sophisticated apps like this. Thanks.