# Selected output elements not pass to rmd document in downloadHandler

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinydashboard

I'd like to create a pdf document with the actual `output` of my dashboard and some additional elements:

1. `titlePanel(title="My Map Dashboard")`
2. `inputId = "Dates selection"`
3. `output$myplot`
4. `output$map`

I'll think in making something like `downloadButton("report", "Generate report")` and set up parameters (`params`) to pass to Rmd document take my target elements for the pdf report creation, but not work yet and the output error is:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4368
Warning: Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading from shinyoutput object is not allowed.
  [No stack trace available]
```

In my example:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.providers)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(sf)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(rmarkdown)
library(rgdal)


# get AOI
download.file(
  "https://github.com/Leprechault/trash/raw/main/stands_example.zip",
  zip_path <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
)
unzip(zip_path, exdir = tempdir())

# Open the files
setwd(tempdir())
stands_extent <- readOGR(".", "stands_target") # Border
stands_ds <- read.csv("pred_target_stands.csv", sep=";") # Data set
stands_ds <- stands_ds %>%
  mutate(DATA_S2 = ymd(DATA_S2))

# Create the shiny dash
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
  titlePanel(title="My Map Dashboard"),  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable0",
                  label = "Type", 
                  choices = c(unique(stands_ds$PEST)),selected = TRUE ), 
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable1",
                  label = "Date", 
                  choices = c(unique(stands_ds$DATA_S)),selected = TRUE ), 
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable2",
                  label = "Project", 
                  choices = c(unique(stands_ds$PROJETO)),selected = TRUE ),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable3",
                  label = "Stand", 
                  choices = c(unique(stands_ds$CD_TALHAO)),selected = TRUE),
      selectInput(inputId = "selectedvariable4",
                  label = "Unique ID", 
                  choices = c(unique(stands_ds$ID_UNIQUE)),selected = TRUE),
      downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("idSaida"),
      fluidRow(
        splitLayout(plotOutput("myplot"))),
      dateInput(inputId = "Dates selection", label = "Time"),
      leafletOutput("map") 
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output){
  
  currentvariable0 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable0})
  currentvariable1 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable1})
  currentvariable2 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable2})
  currentvariable3 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable3})
  currentvariable4 <- reactive({input$selectedvariable4})
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    
    #Subset stand
    stands_sel <- subset(stands_extent, stands_extent@data$ID_UNIQUE==currentvariable4())
    
    #Subset for input$var and assign this subset to new object, "fbar"
    ds_sel<- stands_ds[stands_ds$ID_UNIQUE==currentvariable4(),]
    
    #Create a map
    polys <- st_as_sf(stands_sel)
    ggplot() +
      geom_sf(data=polys) +
      geom_point(data=ds_sel,
                 aes(x=X, y=Y), color="red") +
      xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
      coord_sf() +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(text = element_text(size=10)) 
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    stands_actual<-stands_ds[stands_ds$ID_UNIQUE==currentvariable4(),]
    lng <- mean(stands_actual$X)
    lat <- mean(stands_actual$Y)
    
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = lng, lat = lat, zoom=17) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery) %>%                   
      addMarkers(lng=stands_actual$X, lat=stands_actual$Y, popup="Location")
    
  })   
  output$report <- downloadHandler(

    filename = "report.pdf",
    content = function(file) {

      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(n = c(title="My Map Dashboard", output$myplot,output$map))
      
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
      }
    )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
##
```

Please, any ideas or another way for my problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I believe the following is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175099/reading-objects-from-shiny-output-object-not-allowed

Comment: Thanks, @jwalton the error is almost the same, but the operations involved are very different. Problem not solved yet.